# Calling recording script command of linux terminal from C++ program

Tags: python, c++, linux, c++11, console

Consider the following scenario: I have a Python program that executes a C++ program by using the command `call(["./record"])`. "record" is a C++ executable which containing the following lines:

```
int main(void) {
    system("script --force --flush -q output.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

This turns on console recording.

Next, the Python script should print stuff which I would want to appear in `output.txt`. What I am seeing is that after calling this C++ program the Python prints do not appear and the console is ready. Only when I type `exit` does my Python program continue.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Hi, could you update your post with a clarification on the problem you are trying to solve? That will help us select an appropriate answer ;) thanks!

Comment: Adjust some syntax